# InvalidSearchIdentifierException on using the yodlee testdrive

Tags: yodlee

I have just login to Yodlee platform and exploring the API, I have gone through the quick start and test drive, now I'm getting the InvalidSearchIdentifierException when I'm just using default values provided by test drive sample app. The error shown is

```
{
"errorOccurred": "true",
"exceptionType": "com.yodlee.core.transactionsearch.exceptions.InvalidSearchIdentifierException",
"referenceCode": "_47ee0b3c-ea92-4a7a-9ba7-0a02bad49d47",
"message": "Invalid argument value: com.yodlee.core.transactionsearch.TransactionSearchIdentifier@21d77397"
```

}

but according to the documentaion the search identifier is 192168210225-1377612242609--1002083317-TX_SEARCH mentioned in [link](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getUserTransactions)

please anybody tell me why I'm getting this error

anyway testdrive app is [here](https://devnow.yodlee.com/TestDrive_Old/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are using getUserTransactions API, so I assume you want to get user's transactions. You should be using [excuteUserSearchRequest](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/executeUserSearchRequest) API to get the user's transactions, getUserTransactions API should be used when you user has more than 500 transactions as excuteUserSearchRequest API returns transactions in batches of 500. For more details refer [this](https://developer.yodlee.com/Knowledge_Base/Transactions#Is_there_a_limit_on_how_many_transactions_can_be_retrieved_using_the_transaction_search_API_-_executeTransactionSearch.3F).